# Convert list of tuples such that [(a,b,c)] converts to [(a,b),(a,c)]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

Thoughts on how I would do this? I want the first value in the tuple to pair with each successive value. This way each resulting tuple would be a pair starting with the first value.

I need to do this: [(a,b,c)] --> [(a,b),(a,c)]

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
(t,)=[('a','b','c')]

[(t[0],i) for i in t[1:]]
# [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]
```

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
it=iter(('a','b','c'))
list(itertools.product(next(it),it))
# [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]
```

Using [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

```
it=iter(('a','b','c'))
list(zip(itertools.repeat(next(it)),it))
# [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [('a','b','c')]
a = a[0]
a = [tuple([a[0], a[index]]) for index in range(1, len(a))]
```

Try this !

Answer (score 0):

A solution that uses `itertools`'s combinations module.

```
from itertools import combinations  
arr = (['a','b','c'])
for i in list(combinations(arr, 2)):
    if(i[0]==arr[0]):
        print(i ,end = " ")
```

This would give a solution `('a', 'b') ('a', 'c')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just append pairs of tuples to a list:

```
original = [(1,2,3)]

def makePairs(lis):
    ret = []
    for t in lis:
        ret.append((t[0],t[1]))
        ret.append((t[0],t[2]))
    return ret


print(makePairs(original))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tuples are arbitrary length you can write a simple generator:

```
def make_pairs(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    first = next(iterator)
    for item in iterator:
        yield first, item
```

example result:

```
my_tuple = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
list(make_pairs(my_tuple))
Out[170]: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd')]
```

This is a memory-efficient solution.